# delete all post with certain meta_keys

Tags: menus, post-meta

I'm currently trying to delete metakeys once my plugin is uninstalled to keep the database clean.

My code is as follows:

Array of `meta_keys` that are created

```
$keys = array (
    '_menu_item_icon',
    '_menu_item_hide',
    '_menu_item_block', 
    '_menu_item_center',
}

// Menu items.
        $menu_items = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'   => 'nav_menu_item',
            'numberposts' => -1,
            'nopaging'    => true,
            'fields'      => 'ids'
        ) );


        if ( $menu_items ) {
            foreach ( $menu_items as $post_id ) {
                wp_delete_post( (int) post_id, true );
            }
        }
```

Was hoping to use an array (`'meta_key' => $keys`) for the meta_key and iterate through each but that doesn’t seem to work. Is there a better approach?

Comment: Note that you face memory exhaustion and timeout issues here. Consider setting an upper limit of 20-50 posts, and repeatedly running the code over multiple requests. Eventually no posts will be found. Also consider that post meta queries like this are super expensive, you should do this in a WP CLI command at a time when your server has low traffic